# Show product variants in Search results and auto suggestion instead of individual products

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have a shopify shop using the turbo theme. I would like to show product variants as individual items in the search results page and the auto-suggestion box instead of showing products.

Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you re not a dev, I suggest you should buy an app which provide the function you want or hire a shopify expert so he can help you tweek your theme.

If you re a dev, for show product variants as individual items. You just need

```
{%for product in product.variant%}

Your liquid code

{% endfor %}
```

for the 2nd , find search.liquid in snippet and add some javascript there.